# Create Custom Post Type in Wordpress from database data

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a table on the database, called a garage, made up like this

```
_____________________________________________
|   Brand   | Model   | Color     | Km      |
--------------------------------------------
| Fiat      | Panda   | Black     | 55448   |
---------------------------------------------
| Opel      | Corsa   | Red       | 441155  |
```

I would like to know if I can create a custom post type to view this data.

I created the custom post type, the code is

```
function create_auto_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Auto', 'Post Type General Name', 'Auto' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Auto', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Auto' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Auto', 'Admin Menu text', 'Auto' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Auto', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'Auto' ),
        'archives' => __( 'Archivi Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'attributes' => __( 'Attributi delle Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Genitori Auto:', 'Auto' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'Tutti le Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Aggiungi nuova Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Nuovo', 'Auto' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'Auto redigere', 'Auto' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Modifica Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Aggiorna Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Visualizza Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'view_items' => __( 'Visualizza le Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Cerca Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Nessun Auto trovato.', 'Auto' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nessun Auto trovato nel cestino.', 'Auto' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'Immagine in evidenza', 'Auto' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Imposta immagine in evidenza', 'Auto' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Rimuovi immagine in evidenza', 'Auto' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Usa come immagine in evidenza', 'Auto' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Inserisci nelle Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Caricato in questo Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'items_list' => __( 'Elenco degli Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Navigazione elenco Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filtra elenco Auto', 'Auto' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'description' => __( 'Auto', 'Auto' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-tools',
        'supports' => array(),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'auto', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_auto_cpt', 0 );
```

now how do I go about populating it with the data in the db?
Can you help me ?

Code to create 2 metabox.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );

function my_admin() {
    add_meta_box( 'Car_review_meta_box',
        'Informazioni Auto',
        'display_Car_review_meta_box',
        'Car_reviews', 'normal', 'high'
    );
}

?>
<?php

function display_Car_review_meta_box( $Car_review ) 
{

    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Marca</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" name="garage" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Modello</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" name="garage" value="" /></td>       
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
?>
```

now how can I populate them with data from the database?

Comment: Hi +dimagabri, it is possible. You just need to create a new custom post type. Make some custom metaboxes and then display this data.

Comment: 1. You just need to create a new custom post type: 
2. Make some custom metaboxes
3. querying the database
4. then display this data in the metaboxes after using https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

I saw a similar implementation here - https://youtu.be/hEyC2tU6bLY

Comment: If you add some code, I can help you with that.

Comment: ok i insert the code

Comment: This is good progress. Now create some custom metaboxes and add them to the custom post type. You can skip the part of saving from this  https://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/ since your info is already in the Custom DataBase. I will help write the code to query the database and put the code in the posts.

Comment: ok I managed to create two metabox fields (start with two)

Comment: @omukiguy how do I populate the data now?

Comment: Sorry, I have been unavailable. I am writing some code follow up. is this database already in your wordpress database?

Comment: One more question, is there a way you populate this Database? Do you want to just display the information in CPTs? or do you want the CPTs to take charge now in how the data is updated and saved.

Comment: Any responses to the questions above?

Comment: the database already exists, and I populate it with a form. I would just like to view

Comment: Ok. But that’s for the back end only I presume. Will you use the same CPTs on the frontend? If you are to display the data? I want to fully understand your use case.

Comment: yes I have to show the data also in the front end. by viewing them as a "Blog" page. On the main page all the cars, and clicking on each one to see its characteristics

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Basing on the details you shared above, this tool me a little time to debug. I hope it helps you. I have optimized the code to have some performance.

I added one item to your DB so we can use it as a unique Identifier. See image below. The ID auto increments or adds itself.

[image]

I made a plugin so that deactivating it would turn off the functionality. Of course you can make the plugin better. However, the overall idea,

1. You query the custom post type to find the exiting CPTS,
2. if it empty then DB returns all the cars in it and inserts them in the custom post type
3. Else is get the id of the cars is contrasted to find those already as CPTs and ignores them.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Stackoverflow Question
 * Plugin URI: https://omukiguy.com
 * Author: Laurence B.
 * Author URI: https://omukiguy.com
 * Description: Get the cars from the DB and show case on CPT.
 * Version: 0.1.0
 * License: GPL2
 * License URL: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 * text-domain: prefix-plugin-name
*/

function create_auto_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Auto', 'Post Type General Name', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Auto', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Auto', 'Admin Menu text', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Auto', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'archives' => __( 'Archivi Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'attributes' => __( 'Attributi delle Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Genitori Auto:', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'Tutti le Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Aggiungi nuova Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Nuovo', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'Auto redigere', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Modifica Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Aggiorna Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Visualizza Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'view_items' => __( 'Visualizza le Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Cerca Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Nessun Auto trovato.', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nessun Auto trovato nel cestino.', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'Immagine in evidenza', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Imposta immagine in evidenza', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Rimuovi immagine in evidenza', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Usa come immagine in evidenza', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Inserisci nelle Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Caricato in questo Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'items_list' => __( 'Elenco degli Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Navigazione elenco Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filtra elenco Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'description' => __( 'Auto', 'plugin-auto-text' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-tools',
        'supports' => array(),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'auto', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_auto_cpt', 0 );

add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );

function my_admin() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'Car_review_meta_box',
        'Informazioni Auto',
        'display_Car_review_meta_box',
        'auto', // Change the Car_reviews to custom post type = auto because  register_post_type( 'auto', $args );
        'normal', 
        'high'
    );
}

function display_Car_review_meta_box() 
{
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Marca</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" name="garage" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'model', true ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Modello</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" name="garage" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'brand', true ); ?>" /></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Color</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" name="garage" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'color', true ); ?>" /></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%">Mileage</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="40" name="garage" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'km', true ); ?>" /></td>       
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}


add_action( 'wp', 'techiepress_insert_into_cpt');

function techiepress_verify_existing_cars_in_cpt() {

    $id_arrays_in_cpt = [];
    // Query all autos
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'auto',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $id_arrays_in_cpt[] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'id', true );
    }
    return $id_arrays_in_cpt;
}

function techiepress_query_garage_table( $car_available_in_cpt_array ) {
    // Query Database
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = 'garage'; // If the table has aprefix from WordPress then add $wpdb->prefix . 'garage';

    if ( NULL === $car_available_in_cpt_array || empty( $car_available_in_cpt_array ) || 0 === $car_available_in_cpt_array || '0' === $car_available_in_cpt_array) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
    } else {
        $ids = implode( ",", $car_available_in_cpt_array);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id NOT IN ( '$ids' )";
    }

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
    return $results;

}

function techiepress_insert_into_cpt() {

    // if the queried results from dont match the existing autos
    $car_available_in_cpt_array = techiepress_verify_existing_cars_in_cpt();
    $database_results = techiepress_query_garage_table( $car_available_in_cpt_array );

    if ( NULL === $database_results || empty( $database_results ) || 0 === $database_results || '0' === $database_results) {
        return;
    }

    //Insert into CPT
    foreach( $database_results as $result ) {
         // Create post object
        $car_model = array(
            'post_title'  => wp_strip_all_tags( $result->Model . ' ' . $result->Brand ),
            'meta_input'  => array(
                'id'         => $result->id,
                'model'      => $result->Model,
                'brand'      => $result->Brand,
                'color'      => $result->Color,
                'km'         => $result->Km,
            ),
            'post_type'   => 'auto',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $car_model );
    }
}
```

Code tested and working.

Comment: If this is still a challenge, we can skype and sort it out.

Comment: ok it works but there is a small problem. every time I reload the CPT page in the backend, it adds the 2 values ​​present, increasing them indefinitely

Comment: Can you share your ```var_dump($ids);``` after this line `$ids = implode( ",", $car_available_in_cpt_array);`

Comment: ok.. i insert the code... the output is " 2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2"

Comment: Can you var_dump($results) as well

Comment: is null.. 
it does not compare anything

Comment: If the answer satisfies the Question, please tick it for someone else to pick it up if they ever want something similar.

Comment: If anyone is interested: the answerer even recorded a YT video* ta(l)king us through the thought process. Came here from the video - I greatly appreciate! 

*"Add data from a custom WordPress database table to Custom Post Type"

Comment: I'm aware that YT is somewhat of a "rival platform" but I think in this case, the benefit outweighs that. Not every answer comes with an explainer video.... Maybe include link so I can remove my spammy comment?